# Changing priority of current interrupt in NVIC

Tags: arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling, cortex-m

I have a conundrum. The part I am using (NXP KL27, Cortex-M0+) has an errata in its I2C peripheral such that during receive there is no flow control. As a result, it needs to be a high priority interrupt. I am also using a UART that, by its asynchronous nature, has no flow control on its receive. As a result, it needs to be a high priority interrupt.

**Circular Priority**

The I2C interrupt needs to be higher priority than the UART interrupt, otherwise an incoming byte can get demolished in the shift register before being read. It really shouldn't work this way, but that's the errata, and so it needs to be higher priority.

The UART interrupt needs to be higher priority than the I2C interrupt, because to close out an I2C transaction the driver (from NXP's KSDK) needs to set a flag and wait for a status bit. During this wait incoming characters on the UART can overflow the non-FIFO'd shift register.

In trying to solve an issue with the UART, I discovered this circular dependency. The initial issue saw characters disappearing from the UART receive and the overrun flag being set. When swapping priorities, the UART was rock solid, never missing a character, but I2C transactions ended up stalling due to overruns.

**Possible Solution**

The solution I came up with involves changing interrupt priorities on the fly. When the I2C driver is closing out a transaction, it is not receiving, which means the errata that causes bytes to flow in uncontrolled is not an issue. I would like to demote the I2C interrupt priority in the NVIC during this time so that the UART is able to take priority over it, thus making the UART happy (and not missing any characters).

**Question**

I haven't been able to find anything from ARM that states whether changing the interrupt priority while executing that interrupt will take effect immediately, or if the priority of the current interrupt was latched in when it started executing. I am hoping someone can definitely save from the depths of their knowledge of the architecture or from experience that changing the priority will take effect immediately, or not.

**Other Possible Solutions**

There are a number of other possible solutions and reasons why they are undesirable. Refactoring the I2C driver to handle the loop in the process context rather than interrupt context would be a significant effort digging into the vendor code and affects the application code that calls into it. Using DMA for either of these peripherals uses up a non-trivial amount of the DMA channels available and incurs the overhead of setting up DMA for each transaction (and also affects the application code that calls into the drivers).

I am open to other solutions, but hesitant to go down any path that causes significant changes to the vendor code.

**Test**

I have an idea for an experiment to test how the NVIC works in this regard, but I thought I would check here first. If I get to the experiment, I will post a follow-up answer with the results.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747463/change-priority-level-level-of-running-interrupt-handler which is essentially the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecturally, this appears to be UNPREDICTABLE (changing the priority of a currently active exception). There seems to be no logic in place to enforce more consistent behavior (i.e. the registration logic you are concerned about is not obviously present in M0/M0+).

This means that if you test for the effectiveness of your workaround, it will probably appear to work - and in your constrained scenario it might be effective. However, there is no guarantee that the same code will work on M3, or that it works reliably in all scenarios (for example any interaction with debug). You might even observe some completely unpredictable corner case behavior, but the area-constrained

This is specified as unpredictable in section B1.5.4 of the [ARM v6-M ARM](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0419/d/DDI0419D_armv6m_arm.pdf).

For v7-M (B1.5.4, Exception Priorities and preemption)

> This definition of execution priority means that an exception handler
>   can be executing at a priority that is higher than the priority of the
>   corresponding exception. In particular, if a handler reduces the
>   priority of its corresponding exception, the execution priority falls
>   only to the priority of the highest-priority preempted exception.
>   Therefore, reducing the priority of the current exception never
>   permits:
>
> - A preempted exception to preempt the current exception handler.
> - Inversion of the priority of preempted exceptions.

The v7-M aspect clarifies some of the complex scenarios which must be avoided if you attempt to make use of the unpredictable behavior which you have identified as useful with the M0+ part.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. As this workaround is specific to a silicon errata on this specific M0+ part, if it functions as I hope, then I would consider it a possible workaround. Portability is not a concern. I'll post results after I run the experiment.

Comment: Thanks again. I ran the initial experiment and it looks like the workaround should work in my limited case. If I were using an M3 (or better), is there a similar workaround that could be accomplished using things like PRIMASK, i.e. dropping PRIMASK below the current interrupt's priority while it is executing? I haven't had to dig to this low level on the M3's previously.

Comment: I need to check what the architecte behaviour is, but I believe that is the intened purpose of primask.

Comment: No, PRIMASK and BASEPRI have the opposite effect, if I read them right. A handler can prevent preemption rather than enable it, but v7-M permits the modification by latching the priority level at the _start_ of the sequence.

Comment: I think, now that I have the workaround implemented rather than the simple experiment, I have hit the UNPREDICTABLE you describe. I have a third unrelated interrupt that seems to be having some really odd behavior start when I have the workaround enabled. If I disable it, then it's fine. Looks like I'll need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

**Experiment**

I coded up a quick experiment today to test this behavior on my particular variant of the Cortex M0+. I am leaving this as an unaccepted answer, and I believe @Sean Houlihane's answer is the most correct (i.e. it is unpredictable). I still wanted to test the behavior and report in under the specific circumstances for while I am using it.

The experiment was performed on a FRDM-KL43Z board. It has a red LED, a green LED, and two push buttons. The application performed some setup of the GPIO and interrupts and then sat in an infinite loop.

Button 1: Button 1's interrupt handler was initialized to midscale priority (0x80). On every falling edge of button 1 it would pend the interrupt. This interrupt would toggle the green LED's state.

Button 2: Button 2's interrupt handler was initialized to midscale priority (0x80), but would be changed as a part of execution. The button 2 interrupt handler would run a loop that lasted approximately 8 seconds (two phases of four), repeating indefinitely. It would turn on the red LED and decrease it's own priority below that of button 1. After the four seconds, it would turn off the red LED and increase it's own priority above that of button 1. After four seconds it would repeat.

**Expected Results**

If the hypothesis proves to be true, when the red LED is on, pressing button 1 will toggle the green LED, and when the red LED is off, pressing button 1 will have no effect until the red LED turns off. The button 1 interrupt would not execute until the forever looping button 2 interrupt is of a lower priority.

**Results**

This is the boring section. Everything I expected in the previous section happened.

**Conclusion**

For the experimental setup (NXP KL43Z Cortex M0+), changing the interrupt priority of the currently executing interrupt takes effect while the interrupt is running. As a result, my hacky workaround of demoting priority during the busy wait and restoring it after should function for what I need.

Edit:
**Later Results**

Though the experiment was successful, problems started occurring once the workaround for the original issue was implemented. The interaction between the UART and I2C handlers was relatively consistent, but a third peripheral started having very odd behavior in its interrupt handler. Take heed of the warning of UNPREDICTABLE.

Comment: I've done a similar thing on an M4 core (STM32F401RE), by lowering the priority of fault handlers to allow the USB interrupt to flush any serial output generated by the fault handler. I have not done much testing yet, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution could be to defer to another, lower priority, interrupt for the second half of your processing. A good candidate is the PendSV interrupt (if not already in use), which can (only) be triggered from software.

For a more detailed explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40749331/740048) to a similar question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755276/740048) about PendSV in general.